# python 3.0 pickle.load TypeError

Tags: python, pickle, typeerror

The following code:

```
with open("J:\\python\\.data") as data:
    self.data=pickle.load(data)
```

generated the following error:

```
File "J:\python\code.py", line 50, in get_events
    self.data=pickle.load(data)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I read that I might have to encode it, and I tried utf-8 and that didn't work. What are the other formats? am I going in the right direction?

I forgot to mention that the object in .data is a list and was pickled using protocol 2. the var self.data is a list already

Comment: What's in ".data". What is the item being unpickled?

Comment: LookupError: unknown encoding: binary

Comment: the item being pickled is a previously pickled item using protocol 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
with open("J:\\python\\.data", "rb") as data:
    self.data=pickle.load(data)
```

As noted in the [`pickle` docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler):

> This takes a binary file for reading a pickle data stream.

Thus you need to open it with mode `"rb"` for binary.

Comment: It may be then that the object you dumped isn't Python 3.x compatible. (This is also why dumping to language-agnostic formats can be preferable.)

Comment: I believe that is it, because I ran this in python 2.7 than got python 3.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was trying to open a object pickled under a previous version of Python (2.7).

Once I'd re-pickled it, all was well.